# How to make MarkupExtension visible in Xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, markup-extensions

I am working on a project using Xamarin.Forms.

I have a MarkupExtension for text translations defined in PCL which is
public (so should be visible outside the PCL) and
there is also a static class for PCL initialization and there is a call to its Init method in App contructor

Extension code:

```
 [ContentProperty("Text")]
    public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        readonly CultureInfo ci;
        const string ResourceId = "GymHeroViews.Resources.AppResources";        

        public TranslateExtension()
        {
            ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
        }

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Text == null)
                return "";

            ResourceManager resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId
                                , typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            var translation = resmgr.GetString(Text, ci);

            if (translation == null)
            {
#if DEBUG
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    String.Format("Key '{0}' was not found in resources '{1}' for culture '{2}'.", Text, ResourceId, ci.Name),
                    "Text");
#else
                translation = Text;
#endif
            }
            return translation;
        }
    }
```

Extension is included in GymHero.Common namespace. And output dll's name is GymHero.Common.dll.

In Xaml file I have defined a namespace:

```
xmlns:t="clr-namespace:GymHero.Common;assembly:GymHero.Common"
```

Then I have defined a Button:

```
<Button x:Name="Excersise1GridButton" Text="{t:Translate Excersise1GridButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
```

For me, everything looks as it should but I get the exception:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Type TranslateExtension not
>   found in xmlns clr-namespace:GymHero.Common;assembly:GymHero.Common

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Tomasz

Comment: You should call the library inside C# code before calling from Xaml for loading DLL. Since Xaml parsing and UI instatiation happens on runtime via System.Reflection, you have to do with that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already added a static class to GymHero.Common.dll with empty static method Init and made a call to this method before referencing the extension in Xaml. Still, the problem is the exception I have mentioned in the post above.

Comment: One more thing. I have just checked with process explorer, that devenv.exe has loaded GymHero.Common.dll so there should be no problem with reflection. What can be the reason of the problem?